# Magento2: How to override paypal-express.html & authorizenet-directpost.html?

Tags: checkout, overrides, frontend, payment-methods, magento2.2.2

I want to add unique IDs to the 'place order' buttons on checkout.
I found the right templates on the vendor folder & tried to copy them to my custom theme on app/design:

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html
>   To:
>   app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html

&

> vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/view/frontend/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html
>   To:
>   app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Authorizenet/view/frontend/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html

But it doesn't seems to have any effect on the frontend.
*I already tried to replace 'view/frontend/web/template' with 'templates' on my overrides, still no effect.
*I tried all the obvious stuff like cache flush, static contents, etc...

---

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**
Eventually I created a custom module & overrided the templates using Vendor_Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Authorizenet/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html': 'Vendor_Module/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html',
        'Magento_Paypal/template/payment/paypal-express.html': 'Vendor_Module/template/payment/paypal-express.html'
    }
}
```

};

I then placed the templates under:

> Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html
>   Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

Answer (score 0):

Change and after change clear static content and flash cache.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html
>
> to
>
> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html

And

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Authorizenet/view/frontend/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html
>
> to
>
> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Authorizenet/web/template/payment/authorizenet-directpost.html

Comment: That didn't work. Eventually I ended up overriding those templates from a new custom module (see my update above).